# Evidence of possible tidal effects close to a gravitational wave emitting system

Tags: gravity, cosmology, black-holes, gravitational-waves, tidal-effect

Currently we are attempting to detect gravitational wave emissions using the [LIGO gravitational wave detection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) (and similiar systems), by attempting to detect very weak gravitational waves passing through Earth.

I wonder are there any cosmological observations that are suspected to be the effects of the much stronger gravitational radiation that exists far closer to the actual source?

An example of this effect might be the severe disruption of a star, or a stellar system, which is close enough to a binary black hole system and that exhibits the effects of very strong gravitational waves.

I don't know enough about the subject to ask this question properly, but I would imagine that the material of the star undergoing the gravitational distortion would be accelerated sufficiently to emit radiation that we should be able to detect on Earth.

My apologies if this has already been answered by observations of jets of material from accretion discs or the indirect evidence demonstrated by the contraction of an orbit, [Taylor Hulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_B1913%2B16), but I don't think they are comparable effects to the observations I am asking about.

What I am asking is: is it  possible that  any material closely surrounding each black hole system (or strong gravitational wave emitting system of whatever type, for example the sudden collapse of a large mass star to form a neutron star), has a specific radiation signature particular to it and that we may already have possible candidates tentatively identified?

I would guess that computer simulations are straightforward to perform and give us an idea of the pattern of radiation to look out for and I do understand that to create a good model we would need to know the amount and composition of the surrounding material, but is this idea in principle achievable, or is it already being investigated?

EDIT I based this question around gravitational waves, not gravity waves, my thanks to Qmechanic for clarification END EDIT

Comment: There is a degree to which this kind of questions reads as *"Hey, do you think those LIGO guys have wondered what kinds of gravitational waves sources might be out there?"* Not only have the wondered a lot, but they have calculated many things on the backs of envelopes, lots of things rather more rigorously than that, and a few to a fare-the-well.

Comment: @dmckee I certainly hope it's a small degree, I honestly never thought of it from that angle, but I am learning maybe to research a bit more before second guessing people that have spent their careers thinking about it so I will bear that in mind in future. Thanks very much for taking the time to comment, point taken.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. There are good questions here, but they are more on the lines of "Why doesn't [process X which seems energetic] feature in the expected signals..." or "What are the main background to gravitational wave experiments?". I don't know who among the regulars might know the answers, though. Or if we have an expert lurker.